Finding the shortest path in the movement of an ant inside a cubical room
I came across this question in Pugh's book, which I saw in another question on this site:
An ant walks on the floor, ceiling and walls of a cubical room. If the ants wants to walk from a point p to a point q, how could it determine the shortest path?
My idea is to consider the net of a cube but how to check the shortest path can be a bit challenging. If two points are in the same direction, then the straight path is the shortest, but if they are not in the same direction, one way is to go straight until we have to change the direction to align, but here a shorter path is found with the help of the triangle inequality. I am looking for a precise and formulated way.

It is a poorly formulated problem, but take a look at the first answer here.

@MoisheKohan We want to have an instruction that if given to the ant, it can find the shortest path to move between two points. Is it enough to say that "choose infimum of the paths"?!

By "direction" you mean plane?

@Stefan two points are in the same direction if there is a straight line between them.

Between any two points in space, there is a straight line.

@Stefan this works for example for a spider that can move freely in a 3D space. I mentioned in my question that we are considering an ant walks on the floor, ceiling and walls of a cubical room.

Yes, I know that, I just want to help you formulate what you have tried in a clearer way. What you mean is that both points are on the same face of the cube, i.e. both on the ceiling, both on the floor, or both on the same wall.

But what do you mean by "go straight"?

@Stefan if you consider the net of a cube then my opinion about straight line will be more clear for you.

The word "instruction" does not exist in math. One can say an "algorithm." The trouble is that there is no agreement on what this word means if one works with real numbers. By asking such an ill-posed question, Pugh opens a huge can of worms, most likely, because he did not think seriously about the question. The most intuitive notion is "real RAM" or BSS computational model. But it is controversial. I highly doubt Pugh expected his readers to be familiar with this.

@Alistair Fair enough, I didn't know that term and skipped over it on reading. I'm not sure if nets are the best approach, but you can make your life easier by choosing a net depending on the two points, so that you don't have to deal with the case that the points aren't on a straight line in the chosen net.

@Stefan Thank you. I should thinking more on this.

Due to the shape and symmetry of the cube, the net approach is fine. The ant will never travel across more than 3 faces so place the face where the ant is in the middle of the net and you'll always be able to draw a straight line to the destination.

@Vasili Not necessarily. There is not a straight line between every two points in a net.

@Alistair: we do not need a line between any two points. We need a straight line between the ant and its destination which is always possible if the ant is in the face that is in the center of the net.

@Vasili Yes, the assumption that the ant is in the center face gives us a straight line to its destination, but this line is not necessarily the shortest path. If ant and destination are on opposite faces, their positions inside the faces also matter.

If the ant has a sense for equal incidence/exit angles at crossover edges then the overall flat development of a cube contains  the global shortest path PQ in preference to the local red path PQ.


The path in your image is not the shortest path. Consider other ways to unfold the cube.

Thanks, modified it.

In case that both points are on the floor / both on the same wall / both on the ceiling, the straight line between those points clearly is the shortest path.
In case that you have the points on 2 planes at right angle, you will just have to bend those 2 squares to become co-planar (unwrap the cube faces in the sense of a net), then connect those points by a straight line. - However, there still might be extra cases here. To see those, unwrap the starting side and the target side as becoming co-planar and connected to the incident side of either corner, i.e. thus opening at the edge between those 2 sides having points. This provides 3 coplanar squares in an angled fashion. In that position again draw the line connecting both points. If that line happens to run fully within these 3 squares, then it might happen to become shorter than the former distance, i.e. has to be checked additionally.
In case that the 2 given points are on a pair of cubical faces, which are parallel (2 opposite walls or floor and ceiling), you would have to unwrap it quite similarily to the above case into 3 co-planar connected squares. Within that unwrapping it again is obvious that the shortes path ought be the strait line connecting that given pair of points. However, in this specific setting you would have 4 different choices for the medial square: either of the non-affected cube-faces. Therefore you will have to do the above for any of these choices and thereafter compare those obtained lengths, deciding which of those would be the truely shortest.
--- rk

Your second paragraph is wrong. For instance, if the two points are high up on two adjacent walls, it will usually be shorter to go via the ceiling.

Now having taken account for as well. - Thx for pointing out.
